# Selecting before after character in regex

Tags: php, regex, csv, spreadsheet

Basically I'm trying to get a bit of regex to do the following... I have some data I need to split, the sample data looks like this:

```
Brand Name - Product Name
Another Brand - Shoe Laces
Heinz - Bakes Beans
```

I want to be able to select the brand name or the product name but I can't seem to do it without catching the " - " part in the regex. Anyone tell me what I'm missing out? My regex is pretty basic.

EDIT: I'm exporting a database to a spreadsheet, formatting it and importing it into a new system through a CSV. The old system used a brand name - product name method as above where as the new one uses two separate fields. Ideally I wanted to try and sneak some regex in the spreadsheet formula but now I think its going to be easier to just handle this with a script. Likely PHP although Javascript isn't ruled out.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added my purpose to the post. Shall add it in an edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need a regex for that - a simple `split` would be sufficient.

Example in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from string import strip

s = """
Brand Name - Product Name
Another Brand - Shoe Laces 
Heinz - Bakes Beans
"""

for line in s.split('\n'):
    try:
        brand, product = map(strip, line.split('-'))
        print 'Brand:', brand, '| Product:', product
    except:
        pass
```

Yields:

```
Brand: Brand Name | Product: Product Name
Brand: Another Brand | Product: Shoe Laces
Brand: Heinz | Product: Bakes Beans
```

---

PHP version:

```
<?php

$s = <<<EOM
Brand Name - Product Name
Another Brand - Shoe Laces 
Heinz - Bakes Beans
EOM;

foreach (split("\n", $s) as $line) {
    list($brand, $product) = split("-", $line, 2);
    echo "Brand: " . trim($brand) . " | Product: " . trim($product) . "\n";
}

?>
```

---

Ruby version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

s = "
Brand Name - Product Name
Another Brand - Shoe Laces 
Heinz - Bakes Beans
"

s.split("\n").each { |line| 
  brand, product = line.split("-").map{ |item| item.strip }
  puts "Brand: #{brand} | Product: #{product}" if brand and product
}
```

Comment: Surely you'll want to apply the regex line by line... `'Product Name Another Brand'` doesn't look right at all.

Answer (score 1):

if your data is structured like that, the simplest way is to use whatever split method your language has, then do a split on "-".  eg in Python

```
"Heinz - Bakes Beans".split("-")
```

No need complicated regex

So if your data is in a file

```
for line in open("file"):
    brand,product=line.rstrip().split("-")
    print brand, product
```

If you work with PHP, you can use explode

```
$f = fopen("file","r");
if($f){
     while( !feof($f) ){
        $line = fgets($f,4096);
        list($brand,$product) = explode("-",$line);
        echo "$brand - $product\n";
     }
}
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there won't be any stray hyphens (`-`)  in the string (and that the brand names etc would contain only alphanumerical characters and spaces - to allow other symbols, add them to the character classes `[]` ), you can use following regex:

```
^([\w\s]+?)\s*-\s*([\w\s]+)$
```

The result object will look like:

`$1` Brand Name
`$2` Product Name

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this task. Just find the index of the substring "`-`". Stuff before it is the band name, and after is the product name.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data to be well-formatted, and in particular that the string `-` -- one space, one hyphen, one space -- will only occur as the separator in the middle, you can use `(.*) - (.*)` to retrieve the brand name in the first group and the product name in the second.